# How to add 301 Redirect pages in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, redirect, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I want to add 301 redirects to these URLs -

1-> From `www.abc.com/blog` To `www.abc.com/blog/`

2-> From `www.abc.com/contact` To `www.abc.com/contact/`

3-> From `www.abc.com/catalogsearch/advanced` To `www.abc.com/catalogsearch/advanced/`

I have added this (see screenshot) but it gives me `too Many Redirects` Error -

[image]

Thanx..

Comment: I think the best approach is to set these redirects at webserver level, but before I can help you, I need to know which is the webserver you are using?

Comment: AWS @DianaBotean

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

> Open admin panel > Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites > Add URL
> Rewrites button

Example:-

> select Create URL Rewrite -> custom
>
> Request Path -> [www.abc.com/blog/](http://www.abc.com/blog/)
>
> Target Path -> [www.abc.com/blog](http://www.abc.com/blog)
>
> Redirect Type -> No

Comment: this is not working.